# Can I build a custom Apache Module Extension using C in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, apache, visual-studio-2010, apache-modules

I just am intended to create a custom Apache Module Extension for my project. I am using VS2010 Ultimate edition on Windows Vista 32-bit edition. I started with Win32 DLL project and renamed the extension of the main file to `.c`.

The project configuration is as follows:

```
TargetExtension: .so
RuntimeLibrary: /MD
CallingConvention: /Gd
CompileAs: /TC
```

When I ran Compile[Ctrl+F7] it generated few errors, which were: `C2065, C2167, C2223, C2275` etc. I changed the file extension back to `.cpp` and compiled it as `/TP` and it compiled successfully. But instead of getting a required module name as `infovalley_module` (that I wanted to create) I am having it as `?infovalley_module@@3Umodule_struct@@A`.

First of all I wanted to know why `?infovalley_module@@3Umodule_struct@@A`? Just because of I am using `__cdecl`?

Second of all I want to know can't I compile and build a `.dll` or `.so` file in VS2010 using a `.c` extension?

Last of all - I wanted to get enlightened that unlike `?infovalley_module@@3Umodule_struct@@A` can't creating a custom module in VS2010 has a proper name like whatsoever `auth_basic_module` or `ssl_module` does?

Thank you all in anticipation in advance and sorry for my english term.

Regards,

*** Edit ***

Invoking `apxs -c -i mod_infovalley.c` command not only solved this issue but it brought
another glitch to light. As I issued the command httpd -t it threw:

```
API module structure `infovalley_module' in file path/to/apache/modules/mod_infovalley.so is garbled - perhaps this is not an Apache module DSO?
```

*** Questions ***

1. Any solution(s) to get rid of this?
2. Can I use `apxs` from Windows Vista 32-bit system to create custom Apache Module?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the apxs tool for Win32 module and making a few changes in the configuration section has solved this for me. I now can freely build the custom Apache Module for my project with the name I provided for my module.